# Why are there a transporter room and transporter pads?

Tags: star-trek

It seems it's just as easy to transport someone or something to any part of the ship as a transporter pad (at least TNG era). Other than maybe a place to welcome guests, it seems largely unnecessary (except perhaps particularly complex operations like removing that transporter space worm out of Barclay). Do the transporter room and pads have more power, or other benefit than transporting someone directly to their room/sickbay/bridge?

Comment: Also you might want to have a look at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66509/why-does-everyone-face-the-same-way-on-the-transporter/66848#66848 since it mentions transporter pad efficiency.

Comment: Even if transporter pads aren't strictly necessary, it still provides a designated "arrival and departure zone" for people planning to use transporters.  Helps prevent one person from transporting into the same space in a given hallway where someone else is currently walking.